# How to add styles dynamically from layout folder of zend application

Tags: zend-framework

My all styles are located behind the root under application layout folder. I don't want to keep my styleS in public folder.

How can I read them dynamically in my layout using below commands?

```
$styleFile = "greenish.css"; // from database
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/frontManagement/layouts/styles/'.$styleFile);
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid inline styling and only use `headlink()` but deliver content that is tucked safely away outside the web root or in a db, then it sounds like you'll have to `headLink()` to a dynamic server-side script that accepts the customer identifier and then delivers that customer-specific CSS, complete with mime-type headers.

With clever cache headers and url naming, you might even be able to get this to cache on the browser side, like you'd get with static, totally public CSS resources.

But I'll tell ya, it all sounds like overkill to me. Who cares if all the other styles are 'accessible' as long as you deliver only `stylesheet_XXX.css` to customer 'XXX'? Still, if it's your requirement, then I think you can manage it with the approach above.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to keep your styles/scripts in the public folder? That's where you're supposed to keep them because, well, because their public resources.

Even if you kept them somewhere else, you'd still have to read it and apply the styles to your page. Which means you can't actually hide it (if that's your intention)

Comment: I like the word "why" :) I have hundreds of design with hundreds of sites centerlize from one zend application. I don't want to allow my every customer to access all styles. only that style will load for one's website which is assigned to him. so I want to simple read the css file and load it in the view. any possibility?

Comment: You can block hot linking I guess. But that won't stop anyone from embedding in the page directly.  You could try making the CSS a php file and do some checks on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [HeadStyle](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headstyle) view helper which includes the style sheet inline in the document head. The basic usage is something like this:

```
$styleFile = "greenish.css"; // from database
$style = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH . 'modules/frontManagement/layouts/styles/'.$styleFile);
$this->headStyle()->appendStyle($style);
```

Comment: Infact I don't want add style using headStyle. I want to do this headLink. want to avoid inline styling

Comment: If you want the stylesheet linked but non-public then my only suggestion is to set up a StyleController that serves only the styles the current user can access. It's going to be more load on your server and you have to handle all the cache-related headers yourself to make the stylesheet cache properly.